# How to pass empty DateTime value to json?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have the following json called 'originalJson'

```
{  
  "user_active": true,
  "user_firstname": "Bob",
  "user_lastname": "Tester",
  "user_displayname": "Bobby",
  "user_primary_email": "bob@tester.com",
  "user_login_enabled": true,
  "user_profile": {
       "user_locale": "en-gb",
       "user_lang": "en-gb"
   },
   "user_identities": [],
   "user_roles": [
   {
        "app_id": "74a019c9-7171-4af0-a773-3984edaa35ca",
        "context_uuid": "74a019c9-7171-4af0-a773-3984edaa35ca",
        "context_type": "context_application",
        "role_oid": "test_role_a",
        "role_start_date": "2020-06-27T13:00:00Z",
        "role_end_date": "2021-06-27T13:00:00Z"
    }
  ]
 }
```

and I am trying to replace the role_end_date value with an empty value "".
I have tried changing it to a DateTime? but then i can't convert the jobject value to the right format string.
I have tried the following

```
            DateTime roleendDate = DateTime.Now;
            var emptyDate = roleendDate.ToString();
            emptyDate = null;
            roleendDate = Convert.ToDateTime(emptyDate);
            JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(originalJson);
            jObj["user_roles"][0]["role_end_date"] = null;
            string updatedJson = jObj.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

However it is failing and doesn't like the "jObj["user_roles"]["role_end_date"]" because it is a DateTime type instead of DateTime?. I

Any ideas?

Comment: `I am trying to replace the role_end_date value with an empty value ""`..are you? The code you've shown doesn't appear to attempt that. It seems to try and populate the value with the value of `endDate`...a variable which is not defined in the snippet of code you've shown. Also, you wouldn't want to populate with `""` instead just null it.

Comment: `I have tried changing it to a DateTime?`...what is `it`? Be precise please, so we don't have to infer what you mean.

Comment: `However it is failing and doesn't like`...again, please be precise. If there's an error, tell us exactly what the error message says and which line of code throws it. Progamming is all about precision and detail. Vague descriptions of your problem just make it harder to solve.

Comment: Apologies, yes I have worked out a workaround now, but yes noted, I wasn't at all clear in my question (just read it back to myself). I will bear this in mind next time. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. It would still be great if you could clarify the "it is failing" bit for us as well though. What exactly is the error, and which line of code throws it, exactly? :-)

Answer (score 1):

sorry yes it was failing on this line

```
 roleendDate = Convert.ToDateTime(emptyDate);   because DateTime is not nullable.
```

My workaround was this : to make roleendDate a  DateTime? and then converting it back to an empty string, as it makes the date '1/1/0001'

```
 DateTime? emptyDate = roleendDate;
 emptyDate = null;
 roleendDate = Convert.ToDateTime(emptyDate);

 var nullDate = roleendDate.ToString();
 JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(originalJson)

        if (nullDate.Equals("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"))
        {
            jObj["user_roles"][0]["role_end_date"] = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            jObj["user_roles"][0]["role_end_date"] = roleendDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        }
```